# No Crank, no Start

Tags: honda, starting, crv

2003 Honda CRV, was having slow or hard to start. Now no crank and no start. The battery and starter was taken out of car tested good at two different auto parts stores. I replaced the ignition switch but it still will not start. Can my starter still be bad even though it tested good? All the cables look good - no bumps or corrosion can be seen.

Comment: What happens when you turn the key - do you hear anything?

Comment: just a buzzing noise , everything lights up on the dashboard.

Comment: Is the battery good?

Comment: Yes, everything tested good, fuses, battery, ignition switch has been changed even though it tested good.

Comment: Got another starter anyway, brought a cheaper one. Saved $200.00 and car back running like a new car. Even thought 2 places say my starter tested good. It was not strong enough to start my engine. The answer to my problem was the starter. I hope this helps someone else.